# Asp: Login Control, adding a extra button

Tags: c#, asp.net

When using the login control what would be the best way to get  1 or 2 more buttons to the left of the login button?

To make it short i want the default control as it is, but with another button in the control called "anonymous".

I have already made a custom web user control and made it display succesfully.

Ive tried working with layout template, but without much succes so far.

***LayoutTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID UserName for the username***

Also the login control does no longer display in the design mode for some reason.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4):

You should convert the classic Login control to Template. There is a small triangle in the right corner where you can choose this option

> Convert to Template

After that you can add whatever you like in the table, but you should be careful not to change or remove the controls which are already in the table.

Comment: Heads up, I had my Login control inside of a LoginView control, and the convert to template process would not work until I moved it outside of the LoginView. After the convert to template process, I just moved the new template back inside the LoginView.